# I'm trying to populate an ExpandableListView, why am I getting an error trying to set my custom adapter?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have been attempting to create an ExpandableListView and give it groups and children using a HashMap I created in the MyDataProvider class.  I'm almost successful, but I can't figure out why I am getting this error on setting an adapter.

Here is my Class that will show the list:

```
package com.gmd.referenceapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import com.gmd.referenceapplication.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CommonConstants extends AppCompatActivity {
    View view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_common_constants);


        MyDataProvider dp = new MyDataProvider();

        view=  findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
        HashMap constantsHashMap;
        constantsHashMap = dp.getCommonMap();
        ArrayList constantsHashMapKeys = new ArrayList<String>(constantsHashMap.keySet());

        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, constantsHashMap, constantsHashMapKeys);
        view.setAdapter(adapter);  //error here








        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

Here is my Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by gmd on 6/13/2016.
 */
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private HashMap<String,ListViewItem> constantsHashMap;
    private List<String> constantList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, HashMap<String, ListViewItem> hashMap, List<String> list){

        constantsHashMap = hashMap;
        this.context = context;
        this.constantList = list;

    }



    public View getChildView(int groupPosition,
                             int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild,View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {
        String childTitle = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView childTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
        childTextView.setText(childTitle);
        return convertView;


    }
```

Here is the error:

```
Error:(30, 13) error: cannot find symbol method setAdapter(MyCustomAdapter)
```

I'm sure it's a basic mistake, but I've done some fairly extensive googling and found nothing, so I'd appreciate any and all help.  Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the xml for this activity.  The view I am trying to reference with the view variable is the ExpandableListView here, with the id "expandableList"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.gmd.referenceapplication.CommonConstants">


    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:indicatorLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:id="@+id/expandableList" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The View that you try to use like a ListView does not have a method called setAdapter. The View is the super class of views you has in your android projects. You need to use a ListView instead of View.

Just if you are curious like me, the setAdapter method is added in  android.widget.AdapterView
That is son of ViewGroup, and ViewGroup is son of View.

[image]

First thing, change the like

```
View view;
```

to

```
ListView listView;
```

Remove this

```
setContentView(view);
```

and set the adapter into your listView ref.